# Смена иконки при клике на итем в BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

Есть `BottomNavigationView` с 3 кнопками: домой, корзина и избранное. У них в зависимости от нажатия иконки должны менять цвет (с этого `#BCBCBC` на этот `#000000`). Но почему-то при нажатии они становятся белыми и сливаются с фоном

[image: 1][1]]

activity_main

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
```

navigation_menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_bar_home_selection"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_basket"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_bar_basket_selection"
        android:title="Basket"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_bar_favorite_selection"
        android:title="Favorite"/>

</menu>
```

selection (для простоты выбрал 1 из 3. В остальных тоже самое прописано)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_favorite" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_favorite_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Пытался играться со значениями `true/false`в `selection`, но ничего не меняется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу бросается ошибка в селекторе

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  это при нажатом состоянии  -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_favorite_active"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!--  это значение по умолчанию + должно быть последним -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_favorite"/>
</selector>
```

**UPD**

Так же в xml, ***по желанию***, в `BottomNavigationView` или в его стиль добавьте (отменяет Ripple эффект, когда накладывается белый круг)

```
app:itemRippleColor="@null"
```

Самая изюминка заключается в том, что `BottomNavigationView` по умолчанию накладывает на иконки свой tintColor, по этому программно нужно его убрать

*(котлин)*

```
bottom_navigation_main.itemIconTintList = null
```

*(java)*

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: Не помогло. То же самое поведение

Comment: @Tagir Idrisov, Дополнил ответ

Comment: благодарю, вызов метода itemIconTintList помог